# Реализация браузерных вкладок на vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет. Есть проект на vue с nuxt, и стоит следующая задача реализовать что-то вроде браузерных вкладок в приложении.

Приведу пример: пользователь создает в default layout вкладку "Сессия 1" и далее в рамках этой вкладки он может гулять по информативным страницам приложения. Также он может создать вторую вкладку, перейти на неё, а потом перейти обратно на "Сессия 1", и состояние этой вкладки должно быть таким же как было.

Реально ли такое реализовать?

Comment: фреймы на вкладки )

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Comment: У меня пока проблема с пониманием, как в рамках компонента можно реализовать вкладки, в которых можно без проблем бегать по страницам.